# Swift - Cell in tableview appear over another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am making a simple tableview.

The problem I am facing is that when I scroll down and back up, another cell has appeared over the cells.

Look on the 2 images bellow.

[image]

Here  you see the cell is appeared on the top, and the counter is not zero as the first cell should be. You can also see the color has a darker color.
[image]

Here is the code:

```swift
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
 return 200
 }

 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

 return 1
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

 return 10
 }


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) //as! ArrangementCell


 let card = CardHighlight(frame: CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x + 30, y: cell.bounds.origin.y + 10, width: cell.bounds.width - 60 , height: (cell.bounds.width + 40)/2.6282051282))
 card.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 94/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 0.1)
 card.title = String(Counter)
 card.hasParallax = true
 card.shadowOpacity = 0.6
 card.shadowBlur = 7
 card.cardRadius = 7


 Counter = Counter + 1

 let cardContentVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent") as! DetaljertArrangement
 card.shouldPresent(cardContentVC, from: self, fullscreen: false)

 cell.contentView.addSubview(card)


 return cell
 }
```

How can i prevent this problem?

Comment: Cells are reused and you are adding **always** a new subview.... Use a **custom** cell and add the view (once) in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of cell dequeuing this

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(card)
```

keeps adding a new label every scroll , so you need to create a prototype cell / xib with label hooked as outlet and change it's text

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! That sound logical! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is this line `cell.contentView.addSubview(card)`. You are adding a new content view over the old one without removing the old one. You could try making a UITavleViewCell subclass that has CardHighlight already added and you just update it's title and VC.

DequeueCellAtIndexPath recycles old cells (it only creates new cells initially) so as you scroll you are using the old already set up cells.